# Setting a charset symbol in dylib

Tags: macos, dylib

I use an old Powerbook G4.
While trying to update the macports (sudo port -d selfupdate) following error exist.

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _locale_charset
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/rsync
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _locale_charset
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/rsync
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

How can I set the Symbol _locale_charset?
Does anyone have a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `/usr/bin/rsync` nor `/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib` are part of MacPorts.  Probably you've replaced the system copy of `rsync` with another copy that isn't compatible with your OS X version.  Try reinstalling it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, after reinstalling and patching with this howto: 
http://www.lartmaker.nl/rsync/
macports worked fine for me!